# Unable to import xlsx file in Asp .Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am unable to import xlsx file in Asp .Net getting below error:-

Could not find installable ISAM.

I am using below code for importing xlsx file:-

'function

```
   Protected Function ExcelConnection() As OleDbCommand

    ' Connect to the Excel Spreadsheet
    Dim xConnStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                "Data Source=C:\Users\tcs0028\Desktop\Upload1.xlsx;" & _
                "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"

    ' create your excel connection object using the connection string
    Dim objXConn As New OleDbConnection(xConnStr)
    objXConn.Open()

    Dim objCommand As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", objXConn)
    Return objCommand
```

Plz suggest?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the Connection String first to

Dim ConnStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=~\Upload1.xlsx";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";";

Answer (score 1):

Try [Excel Package Plus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) it's a fork of Excel Package with additional features and it's still maintained and developed.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class ImportExcel
    {
        public DataTable Importar(string arquivo)
        {
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(arquivo);
            string aspas = "\"";
            string Conexao = string.Empty;

            if (ext == ".xls")
            {
                Conexao = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + arquivo + ";" + "Extended Properties=" + aspas + "Excel 8.0;HDR=YES" + aspas;
            }
            if (ext == ".xlsx")
            {
                Conexao = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + arquivo + ";" + "Extended Properties=" + aspas + "Excel 12.0;HDR=YES" + aspas;
            }

            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection Cn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
            Cn.ConnectionString = Conexao;
            Cn.Open();
            object[] Restricoes = { null, null, null, "TABLE" };
            DataTable DTSchema = Cn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Restricoes);
            if (DTSchema.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                string Sheet = DTSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand Comando = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + Sheet + "]", Cn);
                DataTable Dados = new DataTable();
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter DA = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(Comando);
                DA.Fill(Dados);
                Cn.Close();
                return Dados;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

important

> > To import xlsx file you need to be installed AccessDatabaseEngine.exe download from [microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255)
> >
> > While the import is done the user can not be with the sheet open, so it's important to create a copy of this in a temporary folder and pass this path as a parameter. 
> >     (don't forget to delete the temporary)

uses:

```
System;
System.Data;
System.Data.Odbc;
System.Data.OleDb;
System.IO;
System.Reflection;
System.Text;
System.Web;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Excel Package](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Reading%20data%20from%20an%20Excel%20spreadsheet&referringTitle=Home) instead

Comment: Or [Excel Package Plus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), which is based on Excel Package, but is better.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the Connection String first to

Dim xConnStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\tcs0028\Desktop\Upload1.xlsx";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";";

Next thing You need to Install the MSExcel in order to be able to import Excel Files or You can run a free alternative package which will do as if there's an Excel 2007 installed
Here's the link:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=7554f536-8c28-4598-9b72-ef94e038c891&displaylang=en

Hope that helps.